# CSS min-height doesn't seem to work on Jelly Bean

Tags: android, css, android-webview

I'm working on an Android app where some activities and fragments display a Webview. I've noticed that when I run the app in an emulator using Jelly Bean (api 16 and 18), the css property `min-height:100vh` seems to be ignored. This makes the webview look wonky. I've searched online and cannot find anything about why this is or how to fix it.

Comment: is `vh` supported for those versions? http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Ah, no it doesn't. Thanks for the link! If you post an answer based on this, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Android browsers in Jelly Bean (Android 4.1 to 4.3) don't support the `vh` unit.

You can check here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units